# How do I use confirm_form()?

Tags: forms

I have a custom block made in the edit-mode of a node, and I would like to have it linked to a confirmation screen. So I figured out that I'll use [confirm_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/confirm_form/6). After a few days, I'm not able to get this function working.

Is there anyone who can tell me what I do wrong or what I'm supposed to do?

This is the `switch` statement that defines my actions when hitting the button.

```
case ACTION_FICHE_OFFLINE : 
    if ($form_state['buttons']['5']['#value'] == ACTION_FICHE_ONLINE) {
      $form_state['values']['status'] = '1';
        drupal_set_message('FICHE ONLINE', 'warning', FALSE);
    }
    else {
      confirm_offline($form, 'Are you sure?', 'dashboard', t('This action cannot be undone'), 'Confirm', 'Cancel', 'fiche_offline');
      $form_state['values']['status'] = '0';
      drupal_set_message('FICHE OFFLINE', 'warning', FALSE);
}
    break;
```

The formal parameters for `confirm_offline()` are the following ones:

- `$form`
- `$question`
- `$path`
- `$description = NULL`
- `$yes`
- `$no = NULL`
- `$name = 'confirm'`

What code should I use in `confirm_offline()`?

Answer (score 2):

`confirm_form()` is a form builder; as such it should be called from [a menu callback or another form builder function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/calls/confirm_form/7). From the code you shown, I take you are calling it from a form submission handler, and that is not how you should use that function.

As example of code that shows a confirmation form, you can look at [system_modules()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.admin.inc/function/system_modules/7), the form builder associated with the "admin/modules" path. The function contains the following code.

```
  // If the modules form was submitted, then system_modules_submit() runs first
  // and if there are unfilled required modules, then $form_state['storage'] is
  // filled, triggering a rebuild. In this case we need to display a
  // confirmation form.
  if (!empty($form_state['storage'])) {
    return system_modules_confirm_form($visible_files, $form_state['storage']);
  }
```

The form submission handler for the "admin/modules" path, [system_modules_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.admin.inc/function/system_modules_submit/7), then contains the following code.

```
  // Redirects to confirmation form if more modules need to be enabled.
  if ((!empty($more_required) || !empty($missing_modules)) && !isset($form_state['values']['confirm'])) {
    $form_state['storage'] = array(
      'more_required' => $more_required, 
      'modules' => $modules, 
      'missing_modules' => $missing_modules,
    );
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    return;
  }
```

Settings `$form_state['rebuild']` to `TRUE` tells Drupal to call again the form builder which (basing on the value of `$form_state['storage']`) shows the confirmation form, rather than the form listing all the modules found for the Drupal site.

Comment: Thanks for the extra background information! I'll take a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

You need a form, which shows your text and buttons, and you need an URL go call this form.

1. Define your path by implementing [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7). If you are new to Drupal, you should find the [D6 menu system handbook](http://drupal.org/node/102338) helpful.
2. Define a form with help of the [Drupal FAPI](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/group/form_api/7). This [FAPI tutorial](http://drupal.org/node/262422) guides you step-by-step.

You'll find working code examples for both steps in the [Example Module](http://drupal.org/project/examples).

Once this is working, you can call your URL with [drupal_goto()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7).

Comment: Yes I know, but how can I configure the path and the confirmation page?

Comment: What exactly is your problem with the path? From the parameters of confirm_offline I take that you want to show a form which gives the user the chance to say "yes" or "no", right? Did you implement the form and the path in hook_menu? If yes, please show your code.

Comment: Hm, I'm rather new into Drupal and I didn't implement the path (which path by the way).

Comment: @BetaRide isn't drupal_goto() redundant when using confirm_form()? I think [`#action`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#action) takes you to the default path, while the [`$path`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/confirm_form/6) parameter takes you to the canceled action path. I have not used this helper function before, so anyone please correct me if I am wrong.